# Lumen migrate:status fails mysql is ok

Tags: mysql, laravel, lumen

Two distinc lumen installations connecting to the same database, one can connect and the second can not.

They .env file configuration is an exact copy:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=customers
DB_USERNAME=customers_db_user
DB_PASSWORD=customers_db_password
```

the command line mysql tool can connect succesfully:

```
mysql -u customers_db_user -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 9
Server version: 5.7.24-0ubuntu0.18.10.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> use customers_db;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql>
```

but running php artisan migration:status displays an error

> In Connection.php line 664: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for
> user 'customers_db_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL:
> select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema =
> customers_db and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE
> TABLE')
>
> In PDOConnection.php line 31:
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user
> 'customers_db_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
>
> In PDOConnection.php line 27: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for
> user 'customers_db_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Presumably these are on the same server?

Comment: yes, they are. And it is a single server, no cluster or anything like that.

Comment: The password had symbols like # or $ and it needed to be between ''